# How to use css display:none within php email template

Tags: php, html, css

I have been working on a php html email template where i will need to hide a table row when php condition is met, How do i script it?

im using
$htmlContent = '
$htmlContent = '; method

this is my code below:

```
<tr style=""'. ($componentpro2Incwaste ==0 ? " display: none;" : "").'>
          <td>'.$ForSKU.'</td>
          <td>'.$Forption.'</td>
          <td>'.$compwasteQty.'</td>
          <td>£ '.$Fort.'</td>
        </tr>
```

so i think im struggling with this line, doesn't seems to be working, some help.

```
<tr style=""'. ($componentpro2Incwaste ==0 ? " display: none;" : "").'>

$htmlContent = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>NewQuote from Warmup pro</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>New quote</h1>
....
$htmlContent.= '</body></html>';
```

Thanks

Comment: "this is my code below:" - i don't see any.

Comment: sorry just updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, delete one double quote from the start of `style` and add it to the end:

`<tr style="'. ($componentpro2Incwaste ==0 ? "display: none;" : "").'">`

Comment: Ahh bugger, simple tiny quote was troubling me, its working fine mate, Thanks a lot!

Comment: @CoursesWeb  
please help me with this question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64081641/add-div-tag-inside-all-li-with-matching-class-name-using-php/64092865#64092865